# Capybara Unable to find link "Edit" Error

Tags: rspec, capybara

Doing some simple Capybara + Rspec testing:

```
it "Edit Voice and Display the Result" do
  voice = FactoryGirl.create(:voice, title: "Another Random Fact", opinion: "A flock of crows is known as a murder.")
  visit voices_path

  expect(page).to have_content("Another Random Fact")
  expect(page).to have_content("A flock of crows is known as a murder.")

  click_link "Edit"
  fill_in "Title", with: "One More Random Fact!"
  fill_in "Opinion", with: "You cannot snore and dream at the same time."
  click_button "Update Voice"

  expect(page).to have_content("One More Random Fact!")
  expect(page).to have_content("You cannot snore and dream at the same time.")
end
```

When I run the above test, it returns a `Failure/Error: click_link "Edit" Capybara::ElementNotFound:Unable to find link "Edit"` error.

What am I doing wrong here? The link "Edit" is clearly visible on the show page.

show.html.haml

```
%h2= @voice.title
%p= @voice.opinion

= link_to "Edit", edit_voice_path(@voice)
= link_to "Destroy", voice_path(@voice), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}
```

Edit:

Found the error, it was a typo. My apologies. My fix is below

Comment: Please paste the full error log.

Comment: (1) Please post the complete error message (should be 3-5 lines). (2) Post the rendered HTML of the element you are trying to click.

Comment: Hey I actually found a typo in the code, it should be `visit voice_path(voice)`

Comment: Now it is working? So, my guess was correct that `you were not actually visiting the voice page` :-)

Comment: @user3277633 I downvoted and flagged for closing. Since you have a typo, as you call it, it violates one of the flag options. CLOSE > OFF TOPIC > TYPO or simple error

Comment: should I delete the thread completely?

Comment: @user3277633 yes. Delete the entire question. Glad you found your mistake!

Comment: it appears that I can no longer delete the question. Hopefully it'll remind other users that some errors are just simple typo errors

Comment: Try tomorrow? You should be able to delete your own questions. Otherwise, ask a mod for help in SO chat.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't actually navigated to the voice page. That's why you got that error. Make sure you visit the correct `show` page first where your `Edit` button is present.

From your comment and answer, it is clear that, you had an error which caused you not to go to `show` page which I have mentioned in my comment and answer.

Comment: I downvoted because this does not solve the issue. OP already includes `visit voices_path` in his test. The `before` block is to be used before all scenarios in a given context. Also, your solution is wrong. calling `voice_path` will return an error, because the singular-form requires a parameter, being of the object to visit. OP answered his question with the correct solution: `visit voice_path(voice)`.

Comment: @HunterStevens Although, my initial answer was not fully correct, but the direction was right. I mentioned that he did not go to the right page that's why he got that error which turned out correct when he fixed his problem by changing his route. Anyways, I was away and couldn't update my answer. I just updated my answer which is not wrong anymore and I think you should undo your downvote now.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, it turns out I was visiting the wrong page.

Where the code says `visit voices_path` it should be `visit voice_path(voice)`

`voices_path` links to the index, but I want the show page instead, which is `voice_path(voice)`